# ConstraintLayout Group

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I understand that ConstraintLayout.Group is used to associate multiple children of ConstraintLayout Views for displaying or hiding them all at once.

I saw that the code for doing that is inside `updatePreLayout` method of `Group` class which is called from `ConstraintLayout.onMeasure`. 
The problem is that if I set a group visibility to, for example, `VISIBLE`, and then change one of the children (referenced by the Group) visibility to `GONE`, this childView will remain VISIBLE (as group visibility is set afterwards).

Is this a bug, or am I using it wrong?
I know a workaround would be to requestLayout, forcing the ConstraintLayout to update, and set the child visibility after that, but it sounds weird to me.

PS. I read some info about this [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/7gokhq/anyone_have_problems_with_constraintlayout110beta3/) but it doesn't seem to get any answer for that.

Comment: *if I set a group visibility to, for example, VISIBLE, and then change one of the children (referenced by the Group) visibility to GONE, this childView will remain VISIBLE* -- if that is the desired behavior, why is the childview part of the group in the first place?

Comment: @TimCastelijns Because I would like to hide them all at once for instance, but when I show, some of them depend their visibility on some conditions.